# alter northarrow and ruler in mapping toolbox

Tags: matlab

I'm using the mapping toolbox in matlab and have two questions.

In the following:

```
worldmap([48 56],[12 27]);
land = shaperead('landareas','UseGeocoords',true);
geoshow(land,'facecolor',[0.8 0.8 0.8]);

% add ruler
scaleruler('units','km');
setm(handlem('scaleruler'), ...
    'XLoc',-4.8e5,'YLoc',5.4e6,...
    'MajorTick',0:100:400,...
    'FontName','Times New Roman',...
    'FontSize',10,'FontWeight','light',...
    'LineWidth',2,...
    'MajorTickLength',20,'ruler','patches','TickMode','manual');
northarrow('latitude', 54.5, 'longitude', 24.5,'scaleratio', .17);
```

(1) How is it possible to remove the 'N' from the north arrow, and (2) how can I make the ruler to start at'0', it currently starts at 10, which seems a bit weird to me. [image]

I have looked through the documentation but can't find any mention of this.

Comment: The ruler does not start at 10km, but at 0. The 0 is just not printed; the 10 belongs to just after the black bar. If you are into plotting nice maps, consider using [Generic Mapping Tools](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/). It's free and designed to make plots like those, but with pretty looking annotations and colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1-

To have the ruler start from `0` just modify the line as follows:

```
setm(handlem('scaleruler'),'XLoc',-4.8e5,'YLoc',5.4e6,'MajorTick',0:100:400,'MinorTick',0,'FontName','Times New Roman','FontSize',10,'FontWeight','light',...
    'LineWidth',2,'MajorTickLength',20,'ruler','patches','TickMode','manual');
```

## 2-

A hack to "remove" the `N` symbol is as follows:

```
h = handlem('NorthArrow');
set(h,'FaceColor',[0 0 0],'EdgeColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8])
```

It actually makes the color similar to the background color.

The final code and result are as follows:

```
worldmap([48 56],[12 27]);
land = shaperead('landareas','UseGeocoords',true);
geoshow(land,'facecolor',[0.8 0.8 0.8]);
northarrow('latitude', 54.5, 'longitude', 24.5,'scaleratio', .17);
h = handlem('NorthArrow');
set(h,'FaceColor',[0 0 0],'EdgeColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8])

scaleruler('units','km');
setm(handlem('scaleruler'),'XLoc',-4.8e5,'YLoc',5.4e6,'MajorTick',0:100:400,'MinorTick',0,'FontName','Times New Roman','FontSize',10,'FontWeight','light',...
    'LineWidth',2,'MajorTickLength',20,'ruler','patches','TickMode','manual');
```

[image]